# Only allow loggen-in users to view a certain file on server

Tags: php, sql-server, html

So, I have a domain. Let's say my domain was http://www.mydomain.this/ .

If I went into `www.mydomain.this/myfolder/myfile` it would open file `myfile` in the folder `myfolder`. But that is not what I want to happen.

I have an SQL database where I store user login information and each user who has logged in has his or her login cookie. But in the SQL database I also have a column `allow_file` which is either `1` or `0`.

I want the following to happen:

If the user has not logged in at all or does not have **allow_file** set to 1 show the user login screen. But if the user has logged in with an account which does have the permission, show the `.html` page.

How can I achieve this?

***Thank you in advance***

Comment: What kind of web-server are you running? XAMP, IIS etc?